# How to remove content from auxiliary router-outlet

Tags: angular

I am using auxiliary routes in rc5.

I can fill with content just fine.

How can I set the content to null on logout?

```
<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like following

```ts
[routerLink]="['/somePath', {outlets: {'content': null}}]"
```

should do what you want.

Comment: How do I set from type script in my component? So if at login page content is always null

Comment: `router.navigate([/somePath" {outlets: {"content": null}}], relativeTo: route)`

Comment: -1 your "something like" only creates parse errors. there's something really gone wrong with your quotes there. i'm getting a flood of token errors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , does `relativeTo` property still work? I couldn't find it in the Router API reference, so was wondering.

Comment: @Krishnan [router.navigate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor) takes `NavigationExtras` with [relativeTo](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#relativeTo-anchor) which is definitely still required for relative paths.

Comment: You are right. I was silly, checking the `Route` API ref instead of that for `NavigationExtras`. The `relativeTo` option seems quite interesting and powerful. Will try it out surely. Thx